# How can I create a face with a rounded edge?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to fill the empty face. Is there another way than to add vertices along the outlined edge to connect them with the face of the half circle?
[image]

I tried to connect only the four angles of the polygon but the face of the half circle overlaps it.[image]

Comment: Fill with ngon?

Comment: How can I create a ngon with so many faces?

Comment: Box select portion of curve you want to join to straight edge, then add select that edge and F-key fill. Continue until complete? Sorry I'm not much of a modeller

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you considered retopologizing the top part of your object?

If you align the top loops in a perpendicular direction they can perfectly match the remaining half circle border loop and maintain a quad based edge flow.

[image: Edge Flow]

**Edit** A little more detail:

Place the *3D Cursor* correctly aligned at the right depth in relation to the face to be filled.

Erase you top existing faces, select the remaining top curved edgeloop, extrude it with <kbd>E</kbd> but cancel it immediately <kbd>Right-Click</kbd>.

Afterwards, with with 3D cursor already placed as described above, press the <kbd>.</kbd> (Period key) to transform relative to the *3D Cursor* position, scale the edges in the Y axis only with <kbd>S</kbd> > <kbd>Y</kbd> > <kbd>0</kbd> (zero). That should flatten it directly and the right position.

Add one extra edgeloop along the height of the object, connect the two first segments of the bottom circle with the loop, and then you can fill the whole height of the object at once with the *Bridge* operator by selecting only the top and bottom edge loops (not the two large vertical bridging edges).

All done

Comment: This is a really good solution! Could you go into a little more detail?

Comment: very efficient... How do you extrude the edges forming the curved edge?

Comment: @Dontwalk Certainly, updated answer above, hope everything is clearer now, if not just ask, I'll update as soon as I can

Answer (score 1):

Select all the edges your face needs to be connected to then press F.

Answer (score 1):

After adding your glitchy-overlapped polygon, you can press space and look for "Split Concave Faces" (it will only act on the selected faces)
the problem is that the final topology isn't *that* predictable.
but it will render nicely, though.

Comment: whoops. This must be done after Eric Huelin's answer.