# How do I keep my cylinder from being filled?

Tags: modeling

I am making a wall holder for my AC oil. For some reason when I bring it into my print program (Flashpoint) it doesn't see the inner cylinder/hollow.[image: Blender Immage]

[image: Flashprint Image]

Comment: Your model seems to have been made primarily relying on Boolean operations and reeks of bad topology. Boolean operations are bad modelling practice, lazy and [well known for leading to a lot of problems](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=boolean) including this. You model is full of NGons, use [proper topology](http://topologyguides.com) for modelling instead

Comment: This has pretty similar topology, should kickstart you in the right direction https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64121/how-can-i-create-a-face-with-a-rounded-edge/64127#64127

Comment: Not sure how to make the holder hollow/

Comment: I expect the ngons are the issue. Try with [this model](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3615/).

Comment: You're not saying how you export from blender: .stl? .obj? something else?

Comment: I export in STL

Comment: @Samblon, Thanks, it works!!  I am a newbie to 3d printing... Is there no way to make the roundness smoother?

Comment: @Russ Since STL is all triangles (it should), to check how it is really exported, try to import that stl into an empty blender file: if it looks well, is the other program that screws it up. Otherwise, is the export that gets those ngons wrong: then you could convert your mesh to all triangles (or all quads) before exporting. Blender has some helping function to do this.

Comment: not sure how to convert meshto all triangles

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your normals are inverted on the inner faces. In Edit mode, press A to select all, then Ctrl-N and re-export.

Comment: THAT WAS IT!!! You're a Genius ;) !!

Comment: @Russ - If this answered your question, please consider up-voting it and marking it accepted