# My mesh is messed up when I try to add a circular hole in it

Tags: modeling

[image]

It only happens when I enable the subdivision surface, anyone know why it is happening? I am trying to make a studio speaker and I used a knife projection to make that hole in there but that just happens... (the circle's face is deleted)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109618/how-to-connect-a-circle-to-a-grid-with-even-topology/109624#109624

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5856/cutting-a-circular-hole-in-a-hollow-cylinder-without-distorting-the-cylinder also https://topologyguides.com/post/152907366360/cutting-circular-holes-in-curved-surfaces

Comment: https://topologyguides.com/post/140479921825/cutting-custom-shapes and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48954/merge-around-a-face/48967#48967